# using NPM command over CMD not able to install stylus module.. throw error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install the stylus using cmd command. I am behind the proxy. and the proxy configured properly. and I got full access to npmjs.org website too.. I can visit and download any files using browser.

But using my "cmd" command I am getting error like this:

```
D:\test1>npm install stylus
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http 407 http://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
npm ERR! <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
npm ERR! <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
npm ERR! <STYLE id=L_default_1>A {
npm ERR!        FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #005a80; FONT-FAMILY:
 tahoma
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! A:hover {
npm ERR!        FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #0d3372; FONT-FAMILY:
 tahoma
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! TD {
npm ERR!        FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! TD.titleBorder {
npm ERR!        BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid;
PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; B
ORDER-LEFT: #955319 0px solid; COLOR: #955319; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid;
 FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! TD.titleBorderx {
npm ERR!        BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid;
PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; B
ORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #978c79; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid;
 FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .TitleDescription {
npm ERR!        FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: t
ahoma
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! SPAN.explain {
npm ERR!        FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! SPAN.TryThings {
npm ERR!        FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .TryList {
npm ERR!        MARGIN-TOP: 5px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: bla
ck; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .X {
npm ERR!        BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid;
FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #7b
3807; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR:
#d1c2b4
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .adminList {
npm ERR!        MARGIN-TOP: 2px
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! </STYLE>
npm ERR! <META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1170" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
npm ERR! <BODY bgColor=#f3f3ed>
npm ERR! <TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
npm ERR!   <TBODY>
npm ERR!   <TR>
npm ERR!     <TD class=titleBorderx width=30>
npm ERR!       <TABLE height=25 cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=0 width=25 bgColor=bla
ck>
npm ERR!         <TBODY>
npm ERR!         <TR>
npm ERR!           <TD id=L_default_x class=x valign=middle align=center>X</TD>
npm ERR!         </TR>
npm ERR!         </TBODY>
npm ERR!       </TABLE>
npm ERR!     </TD>
npm ERR!     <TD class=titleBorder id=L_default_2>Network Access Message:<SPAN c
lass=TitleDescription> The page cannot be displayed</SPAN> </TD>
npm ERR!   </TR>
npm ERR!   </TBODY>
npm ERR! </TABLE>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <TABLE id=spacer>
npm ERR!   <TBODY>
npm ERR!   <TR>
npm ERR!     <TD height=10></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
npm ERR! <TABLE width=400>
npm ERR!   <TBODY>
npm ERR!   <TR>
npm ERR!     <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
npm ERR!     <TD width=400><SPAN class=explain><ID id=L_default_3><B>Explanation
:</B></ID></SPAN><ID id=L_default_4> There is a problem with the page you are tr
ying to reach and it cannot be displayed. </ID><BR><BR>
npm ERR!     <B><SPAN class=tryThings><ID id=L_default_5><B>Try the following:</
B></ID></SPAN></B>
npm ERR!       <UL class=TryList>
npm ERR!         <LI id=L_default_6><B>Refresh page:</B> Search for the page aga
in by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet
 congestion.
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_7><B>Check spelling:</B> Check that you typed the Web
page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped.
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_8><B>Access from a link:</B> If there is a link to the
 page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!       </UL>
npm ERR! <ID id=L_default_9>If you are still not able to view the requested page
, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</ID> <BR><BR>
npm ERR!     </TD>
npm ERR!   </TR>
npm ERR!   </TBODY>
npm ERR! </TABLE>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <TABLE id=spacer><TBODY><TR><TD height=15></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <TABLE width=400>
npm ERR!   <TBODY>
npm ERR!   <TR>
npm ERR!     <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
npm ERR!     <TD width=400 id=L_default_10><B>Technical Information (for support
 personnel)</B>
npm ERR!       <UL class=adminList>
npm ERR!         <LI id=L_default_11>Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Requir
ed. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the W
eb Proxy filter is denied. (12209)
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_12>IP Address: 172.19.63.99
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_13>Date: 6/2/2014 2:29:42 PM [GMT]
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_14>Server: BSDVMTMG004.mahindrasatyam.ad
npm ERR! <LI id=L_default_15>Source: proxy
npm ERR!
npm ERR!       </UL>
npm ERR!     </TD>
npm ERR!   </TR>
npm ERR!   </TBODY>
npm ERR! </TABLE>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! </BODY>
npm ERR! </HTML>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:239:23)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\np
m\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:211:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:123:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\request\request.js:893:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_
modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:844:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:919:16
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "stylus"
npm ERR! cwd D:\test1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\test1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How to fix this? any help? thanks in advance

Comment: Ever figure it out? I have the same problem.